# Teradata min and max dates Find the Employees Start Date and Time and End Date and Time for each date

Tags: datetime, teradata

I have columns AssignedTo, InternalID, Task Function, Min(STARTDATE), Max(ENDDATE)

| AssignedTo | InternalID | Task Function | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 67077 | Write the letter | 08/24/2017 05:30 AM | NULL |
| Joe | 16354 | Send the letter | 08/24/2017 06:30 am | 08/24/2017 07:30 am |
| Joe | 16359 | Mail Letter | 08/24/2017 08:32 am | 08/24/2017 08:35 am |
| Joe | 13340 | Call to Member | 08/24/2017 09:32 am | 08/24/2017 10:35 am |
| Joe | 13318 | Fax to Member | 08/24/2017 12:01 pm | 08/24/2017 12:05 am |
| Joe | 14895 | Fax to Member | 8/20/2017 11:28:34 PM | 8/20/2017 11:28:34 PM |
| Joe | 79806 | Call to Member | 08/24/2017 03:30pm | 08/24/2017 04:30 PM |

Trying to create 1 line line this:

| Assigned TO: | Date: | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 08/24/2017 | 08/24/2017 05:30 AM | 08/24/2017 04:30 PM |

I want the first Start Date and last End Date for each day the assigned to is in the system for that day. I'm using teradata. i'm sure this has been asked some where i just have not been able to locate it. Or I have been over thinking this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68884987/2527905

Answer (score 1):

Considering the example you provided it seems that overlapping is not important for you.

I consider `startdate` and `enddate` as `timestamp(0)` columns.

Please check the following code:

```
select assignedTo, cast(startdate as date),
min(startdate), max(enddate)

from
my_table

group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```